# CKEditor on iOS 10

Tags: ios, ckeditor

there is a new issue on CKEditor when running on iOS10.

When the content is bigger than the editor, and I want to write some stuff at the beginning, there is a weird scrolling issue. It seems to scroll back automatically at the end of the editor, and sometimes the carret is outside the window. It only happens on iOS10 (tested with Safari and Chrome, both latest versions available), and it even happens on the CKEditor demo page (http://ckeditor.com/demo/demo03.html) when you try to write some text at the beginning. Everything is working perfectly on iOS9.

Anyone had this issue? Is there a quick hack that I can put together to make it work correctly? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem using CKEditor's "Div Editing Area" plugin (puts the editor in a div instead of an IFrame).